# Signed short передать посредством unsigned char массива?

Tags: c++

Есть переменная типа `signed short`. Ее необходимо загнать в `unsigned char` массив, для дальнейшей передачи по сети.
Как это сделать?

Comment: А вот тут и всплывает вопрос об архтектуре (big endian--little endian). Более всего нравится комментарий @avp -- при таком подходе эти проблемы уже учтены.

Answer (score 1):

Выделяем подходящий по размеру буфер char, берем указатель на наши данные, приводим его к целевому типу, перемешаясь указателем, копируем данные в буфер. Ну а буфер шлем. На "том конце" обратная операция, если считать размеры sizeof(signed short) равными на обеих машинах.

```
signed short some_val = 333;
unsigned char* cbuffer = new unsigned char[sizeof(signed short)];

unsigned char* pointer_to_value = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&some_val);

for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(signed short); ++i) {
    cbuffer[i] = pointer_to_value[i];
}

delete [] cbuffer;
```

Comment: Не забудьте про `hton*` ещё.

Comment: А можно и проще


    #include <string.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    
      ....
    
      char cbuffer[YOUR_BUFFER_SIZE], *pc = cbuffer;  
      short short_to_send, ts;
      .....
      ts = htons(short_to_send);
      memcpy(pc, &ts, sizeof(ts));
      pc += sizeof(ts); // это для заполнения остальной част буфера

Хотя это и Си код, но g++ не ругается.